# trying to get data from firestore but getting this ERROR

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to get data from Firebase Firestore and getting the following error, the same code was working a month ago with my other app, it would be great if you could help

**Class 'List' has no instance getter 'lenght'.
Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: lenght**

```
    return Scaffold(
                body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Sell')
              .orderBy('TS', descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null)
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  valueColor:
                      new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.cyan[400]),
                ),
              );
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.lenght,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 120,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                              spreadRadius: 2,
                              blurRadius: 3)
                        ]),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 120,
                          height: 120,
                          child:ClipRRect(
                                 child: Image.network(
                                    snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                        .get('image 1 Url'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                )),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              snapshot.data.documents[index].get('name'),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontFamily: 'font',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `lenght` to `length`

That's a typo i think. If you wondering why `length`. That's because you are trying to get the length of `snapshot.data.documents` and initialise it to `itemCount` to allow the list to loop your item. I hope this solution works for you.